# Sql server Query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a query which work fine with sql server but error in mysql

this is the error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect parameter      count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'

And this is my query:

```
            String sql = "SELECT SUM(Pay) AS Pay, ClinicId, DATE_FORMAT     
            (DATENAME(MONTH,     Date)) as Months " 
            +"FROM Prescription GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT (DATENAME(MONTH,    
            Date)), ClinicId HAVING ClinicId = '"+cid+"'";
```

Comment: Very hard to search the docs `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M')`

Comment: Thanks Mihai it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you checked out the MySQL documentation on [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function, you would have noticed that it requires 2 parameters, not just one:

> DATE_FORMAT(date,format)
>
> Formats the date value according to the format string.

You probably need the `date_format(Date, '%M')` expression. The linked documentation contains all the formatting options, so you can play around with it to tailor the output to your needs.